# MyISAM table keeps crashing. How to go about finding the cause or debugging it?

Tags: mysql, myisam, elgg

On one of the site's I manage, I have a table set to MYISAM, and it constantly crashes. Automatic repair fails every time, so I have to go in and run the `REPAIR TABLE` command. I've looked at possible solutions such as this one: [MySQL table is marked as crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869377/mysql-table-is-marked-as-crashed/11869634#11869634) 
 and it looks likes the best way might be to change the table to InnoDB.

However, the table has a FULLTEXT index, and if I could remove it then it would be no problem, but the site is running on a framework (specifically Elgg), so I don't know what kind of damage or problems I may have later on, so that might not be a good option.

So for my question: How can I find the cause of the crash? The site is on a web host, and running on PHP.

Comment: Put a trouble ticket into your hosting provider company, to find out whether their mysqld server software is crashing a lot.  If it is, ask them to move your database to a different MySQL server machine. Or, fire your hosting provider and get a better one.  Also, ask about this on the Elgg support forum.  This shouldn't happen unless something is terribly wrong.

Comment: How often are your writing to the database? If you're running a huge volume of `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s on the table you might want to start using transactions... but if you're not running hundreds of writes a minute I'm inclined to agree with Ollie Jones on this... it really shouldn't happen unless there's something wrong with MySQL.

Comment: Is the MySQL server itself crashing? Check the uptime of the server with `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'`. If the server uptime is short, it's more likely that the whole server is crashing which could be a much different solution.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I would assume not because, although I'm not too sure how the web host handles it's databases, but I have many other databases/tables for different sites under the same account and all of those are fine. the only thing crashing is one specific table for one specific database/site everytime.

Answer (score 0):

It may due  to large number of connections on the same table then allocated in the my.cnf file.

As MyISAM locks the table and all threads remain in waiting list.